# Remove all non numeric characters except first + operator

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove all non-numeric characters except the first + operator.

**So + operator should show at the first.**

For example,

+614a24569953 => +61424569953

+61424569953+ => +61424569953

Comment: For cases like `6142+4569a9+53` or `61a42+4569a9+53` (the `+` is not at the beginning of the string) the pure regexp solution seems to be (very) difficult

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski sorry no. All + will be removed in 2 string you mentioned.
 (?!^\+)[^\d\r\n]+ helped me.

Comment: ok now I get it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe,

```
(?!^\+)[^\d\r\n]+
```

replaced with an empty string would simply do that.

---

The first statement,

```
(?!^\+)
```

ignores the `+` at the beginning of the string, and the second one,

```
[^\d\r\n]+
```

ignores digits, newlines and carriage returns in the string.

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pXo7OW/1/)

#### Test

```js
const regex = /(?!^\+)[^\d\r\n]+/g;
const str = `+614a24569953`;
const subst = ``;

const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

---

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/wfkuxk/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/wfkuxk/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: This won't work.
This keeps second + operator on "+614a2+4569953"

Comment: @Emma yes - you are right - however for case when `+` is not at the beginning of the string - I think - solution is highly non-trivial in pure regexp (my answer have problem with case `61a42+4569a9+53` - letter `a` before `+`). Nice example of simple question with not simple answer

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
t1="+614a24569953"
t2="+61424569953"
t3="6142+4569a9+53"

re = /(?<=\+.*)[^0-9]/g


console.log( t1.replace(re, '') );
console.log( t2.replace(re, '') );
console.log( t3.replace(re, '') );
```